# Can i release my app with .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(43200) like this?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I read on firebase the fetch interval should be 12 hours when releasing the app, so I put 43200 seconds on .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(43200) that translates to 12 hours. Should I release my app like this? Am I doing something wrong? am I missing something?

here is my firebase remote config code:

```
 //firebase remote configuration
    // default value
    firebaseDefaultMap = new HashMap<>();
    firebaseDefaultMap.put(SET_MAX_PROGRESS, 10000);
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(firebaseDefaultMap);

    //debug mode ON !!I SHOULD TURN IT FO BEFORE RELEASE!!
   /* mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(
            new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    .build());*/

    mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(43200)
            .build();
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);

    progress = view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    target_users = view.findViewById(R.id.target_users);
    //Fetch listener
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                Log.d(TAG, "Fetched value: " + mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(SET_MAX_PROGRESS));
            }else{
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Default value: " + mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(SET_MAX_PROGRESS));
        }
    });
    int max = (int) mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getDouble(SET_MAX_PROGRESS);
    target_users.setText("Target: "+ max);
    progress.setMax(max);
    //end firebase remote configuration
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cant comment yet so posting it as an answer.
Yeah you can publish your app with the 43200 seconds interval and its even recommended. think of the next senario:

Your app has 10000 users and you make a change to your firebase but your interval is 0 for exmaple. that means that immediately all the connected users will reach the firebase and retrieve the new values, thats obviously not good. the interval is created in order to reduce stress on the servers.

Also if I'm not wrong if you remove this line:

```
.setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(43200)
```

It wont make any difference because its a default value.
Cheers

Comment: Thank you @Ofek for your helpful answer this was what I needed so as you said as long as the fetch interval is more than 12 hours there should be no problem, so I'm safe to release my app like this